# Comparar resultados

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Estoy haciendo el juego piedra,papel y tijera con React y hooks.
El codigo:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./Pie.css";
import img1 from "./img/piedra.png";
import img2 from "./img/papel.png";
import img3 from "./img/tijera.png";
const opcionesCPU = [img1, img2, img3];
const a = ["piedra", "papel", "tijera"];

const u = [
  {
    img1: false,
    descripcion: "piedra"
  },
  {
    img2: false,
    descripcion: "papel"
  },
  {
    img3: false,
    descripcion: "tijera"
  }
];

const Pie = () => {
  const [correctas, setCocrrectas] = useState(0);
  const [incorrectas, setIncorrectas] = useState(0);
  const [empate, setEmpate] = useState(0);
  const [imagencpu, setImagenCpu] = useState();
  const [imageClicked, setImageClicked] = useState(u);

  const ClickImagencpu = () => {
    const aleatorio = Math.floor(Math.random() * opcionesCPU.length);
    if (u[0].descripcion && a[aleatorio] === "tijera") {
      setCocrrectas(correctas + 1);
    } else if (u[0].descripcion && a[aleatorio] === "papel") {
      setIncorrectas(incorrectas + 1);
    } else {
      setEmpate(empate + 1);
    }
    setImagenCpu(opcionesCPU[aleatorio]);
  };

  const onClickHandler = (order) => {
    const resetImages = {
      piedra: false,
      papel: false,
      tijera: false
    };
    setImageClicked({
      ...resetImages,
      [order]: true
    });
  };
  return (
    <div className="Ccontainer">
      <h2>partidas ganas : {correctas} </h2>
      <h2>partidas perdidas : {incorrectas} </h2>
      <h2>partidas empatadas : {empate} </h2>
      <div>
        <div className="image">
          {imageClicked.piedra && <img src={img1} alt="Piedra" />}
          {imageClicked.papel && <img src={img2} alt="Papel" />}
          {imageClicked.tijera && <img src={img3} alt="Tijera" />}
          {imagencpu && <img src={imagencpu} alt="imagencpu" />}
        </div>
      </div>

      <button onClick={() => onClickHandler("piedra")} className="ground">
        Piedra
      </button>
      <button onClick={() => onClickHandler("papel")} className="ground">
        papel
      </button>
      <button onClick={() => onClickHandler("tijera")} className="ground">
        tijera
      </button>
      <button onClick={() => ClickImagencpu()}>CPU</button>
    </div>
  );
};
export default Pie;
```

En la función `ClickImagencpu`  obtengo un numero aleatorio del array `opcionesCPU` .
Luego comparo comparo lo que jugo el usuario y la maquina y determina si el usuario gano la partida o si la perdió o fue un empate,el problema es cuando el usuario juega con papel compara el resultado de piedra vs cpu por ejemplo `papel === papel` da como resultado victoria para el usuario ya que toma la comparación de `piedra === papel` , que forma puedo comparar cada juego(piedra vs cpu , papel, vs cpu, tijera vs cpu) y obtener diferentes resultados.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes hacer de esta forma, ahí lo he hecho a mi forma porque no entendía el nombre de tus variables, pero lo importante está en el if de la función "ClickImagencpu":

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import img1 from "./piedra.png";
import img2 from "./papel.png";
import img3 from "./tijera.png";

const options = [
  { option: "piedra", imageUrl: img1 },
  { option: "papel", imageUrl: img2 },
  { option: "tijera", imageUrl: img3 },
];

const App = () => {
  const [userState, setUserState] = useState({ win: 0, lost: 0, draw: 0, });
  const [userOptionSelected, setUserOptionSelected] = useState({ option: "", imageUrl: "", });
  const [cpuOptionSelected, setCpuOptionSelected] = useState({ option: "", imageUrl: "", });

  const ClickImagencpu = () => {
    const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * options.length);
    const cpuSelected = options[random];
    const userSelected = userOptionSelected.option;

    if (
      (userSelected === "tijera" && cpuSelected.option === "papel") ||
      (userSelected === "piedra" && cpuSelected.option === "tijera") ||
      (userSelected === "papel" && cpuSelected.option === "piedra")
    ) {
      setUserState({ ...userState,  win: userState.win + 1});
    } else if (userSelected === cpuSelected.option) {
      setUserState({ ...userState,  draw: userState.draw + 1});
    } else {
      setUserState({ ...userState, lost: userState.lost + 1 });
    }
    
    setCpuOptionSelected({
      option: cpuSelected.option,
      imageUrl: cpuSelected.imageUrl,
    });
  };

  const onClickHandler = (userSelected) => {
    const optionSelected = options.filter(({ option }) => option === userSelected)[0]
    setUserOptionSelected({
      option: optionSelected.option,
      imageUrl: optionSelected.imageUrl,
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className="Ccontainer">
      <h2>partidas ganas : { userState.win } </h2>
      <h2>partidas perdidas : { userState.lost } </h2>
      <h2>partidas empatadas : { userState.draw } </h2>
      <div>
        <div className="image">
          { userOptionSelected.imageUrl ? <img src={ userOptionSelected.imageUrl } alt={ userOptionSelected.option } /> : <></>}
          { cpuOptionSelected.imageUrl ? <img src={ cpuOptionSelected.imageUrl } alt="imagencpu" /> : <></>}
        </div>
      </div>
      {
        options.map(({ option }) => (
          <button key={ option } onClick={() => onClickHandler(option)} className="ground">
            { option }
          </button>
        ))
      }
      <button onClick={() => ClickImagencpu()} disabled={ !userOptionSelected.imageUrl ? true : false }>CPU</button>
    </div>
  );
};
export default App;
```